# How to compile a C source file to make a custom library?

Tags: c, include

I have a source file `handleSSV.c` that I would like to compile to make a custom library. How do I do that?

I'm thinking:

```
gcc -o handle.h handleSSV.c
```

and then,

```
#include "handle.h"
```

when I want to use `handleSSV.c`?

Answer (score 3):

It varies by platform, but the header (`handleSSV.h`) will not be generated by the C compiler; you will create that from the information in the source.  This sequence of commands is 'typical' for Unix-like platforms.

```
gcc -c handleSSV.c                           # Generates handleSSV.o
ar r libhandleSSV.a handleSSV.o              # Creates static library
gcc -o ssv-prog ssv-prog.c -L . -lhandleSSV  # Creates program with library
```

If you want to build a shared library, then you have to use something like:

```
gcc -fPIC -o libhandleSSV.so -shared handleSSV.c
```

The link line for the program doesn't change.  Note that the `.so` suffix is widely but not universally used (`.sa` on older AIX; `.shl` on older HP-UX; `.dylib` on Mac OS X, etc).

The rules are similar but different in detail on Windows.

---

### Demonstration

Demonstration code run on Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks using GCC 4.8.2.

#### handler.h

```
#ifndef HANDLER_H_INCLUDED
#define HANDLER_H_INCLUDED

extern int handler(int a, int b);

#endif /* HANDLER_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### handler.c

```
#include "handler.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int handler(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a + b;
    printf("%d = %d + %d\n", c, a, b);
    return c;
}
```

#### use-handler.c

```
#include "handler.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int d = handler(29, 31);
    printf("d = %d\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation of static and shared library, etc

```
$ gcc -c handler.c
$ ar r libhandler.a handler.o
ar: creating archive libhandler.a
$ gcc -o use-handler use-handler.c -L. -lhandler
$ ./use-handler
60 = 29 + 31
d = 60
$ gcc -o libhandler.dylib -shared -fPIC handler.c
$ gcc -o use-handler use-handler.c -L. -lhandler
$ otool -L use-handler
use-handler:
    libhandler.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /usr/gcc/v4.8.2/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
$ ./use-handler
60 = 29 + 31
d = 60
$
```

Comment: I am sorry the last line does not seem to work. the 2 first are find I am on Mac UNIX, and the program is actually call handle.c and not handleSSV.c sorry about the confusion. Do you mind looking at it again?

Comment: The source file and library names are arbitrary.  I've updated the answer with a 'fully tested' static and shared library built with GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2.  If the technique doesn't work for you, then you need to show what errors you're getting.  The chances are you've got a dependency on other libraries, and haven't taken those into account yet. Although I didn't show it, the code also compiles clean with stringent compiler warning options: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c handler.c`, etc.